# When (La)TeX says "some message on input line XYZ" - where's that line?

Tags: compiling, warnings, logging

I'm sure this is a dupe, but I'll go ahead anyway:

LaTeX relates many of its messages to lines in files. For example:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+lmtt on input line 81.
```

But it is often unclear which line of which file is it referring to. Whether it's always a .tex file or possibly a .sty or .cls; whether its the file in its original form, or after it has had some macro expansion; etc. If you try looking for the filename in the lines before the message, you find many filenames, none of which were written by you (e.g. `epstopdf-sys.cfg`, `grfext.sty`, `omslmsy.fd`, taken from the same example - which I won't fully list here, since this question is more general).

So is there a simple rule or determining where in the input the message relates to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look in the log file, every time TeX opens a file it prints a `(` followed by the path to the file, and when it closes a file it prints a `)` so by matching (or more likely getting your editor to match for you) `()` pairs you can work out the currently open file for any message in the log.

The same is needed for error messages where the number is given as `l.56` but there modern TeX systems have a command line option (`--file-line-error`) to put the filename into the error message, but that name is not available to macro generated messages, even if the option is used.

Comment: But what if one file uses macros from another file which uses macros from another file etc. - the inner files are themselves ok, but the errors occur on the inside. How do I get the stack of file-lineno, file-lineno etc.?

Comment: @einpoklum as I say above if the log says `(filea  (fileb... (filec..) ..  error on line 5` by matching braces you can deduce it is line 5 of `fileb`

Comment: but not which line of `filea`...

Comment: @David: I think that what he means is that it might be hard to trace the error back to where fileb is called in the original document.

Comment: @MartinArgerami that's life:-)

Comment: I guess you've answered my question, so I have to accept, but I'm deeply unsatisfied. Hrrmph.